# Torsion of an elliptic curve injects under reduction - question

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E/K$  be an elliptic curve over a number field. I am interested in the folowing statement: the map $E(K)[m]\rightarrow \tilde E_v(\tilde k_v)$ is injective for any place of $K$ provided there is good reduction at $v$. The proof from Silverman's book uses the formal group of $E$. But what about the argument of the following type. Say $E$ has a Weierstrass equation with coefficients in $\mathcal O_K$. Then the affine torsion points have also coordinates in $\mathcal O_K$ thus they cannot reduce to $\tilde O$. Therefore reduction is injective. In particular I am interested in the following case $E_B\colon y^2=x^3+B$ and $m=3$. For primes not dividing $6B$ I think we can immediately deduce injectivity of $E(K)[3]\rightarrow \tilde E_v(\tilde k_v)$. Does this argument work more generally?

Comment: In general the torsion points need not have coordinates in $O_K$. See Theorem VIII.7.1 in Silverman's book.

Comment: The proof that torsion points have integral coordinates (at a place of good reduction) is basically the same as the injectivity. The proofs I know are either using the formal group directly or are inspired by that argument.